# linux max disk size

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I have a linux server with sda to host the OS (Ubuntu 7.04, ext3 filesystem) and sdb,sdc,sdd,sde 1TB each to be on a raid 1 for saving data. I need to get rid of the raid and I wanna swap it for a 4TB disk. How can I determine which is the max disk space that is supported?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using a 7 year old version of Ubuntu?  7.04 hasn't had security updates for years now.

Comment: unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 5):

Linux is not really the limiting factor when it comes to max disk size, as long as you stick to ext3,4 or xfs. If you are running a recent main board with SATA you are good to go, since SATA has 48bit LBA to address the disk.

See http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/246170-32-hard-drive-size-limit

Ext3 has some limits on max disk size, due to the chosen block size. With a block size of 4KiB the maximum file size is 2TiB and the max disk size 16TiB.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3

Another very insightful read is here:
[What is the max partition supported in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33555/what-is-the-max-partition-supported-in-linux)

Comment: Not true, block device sizes have a maximum in linux, although it is quite large.

Comment: True. But my response applies to the given context.

Comment: True. (--- expansion ---)